# How to grab a specific part of a returned GET in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, get

I am trying to return a webpage, and grab the part of the page labeled: Description. I want to be able to split the returned HTML, but with the "" that are in HTML it will not work correctly.

This is for a template to allow a user on an extension to be able to add a pre-loaded string to fill in a box. I have tried splitting the string at a set word, but my knowledge does not extend past trying to use the string.

```
function pullWebpage(){
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    var response = this.responseText;
    response.split("Description");
    console.log(response);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://jira2.cerner.com/browse/ION-25843?", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

xhr.send(data);
}
```

I want to be able to successfully pull out the description of the page pulled in the GET, and use this to set up an automatic template. HTML returned in GET using postman [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIvSc.png)

Comment: What kind of response does your GET request returns?

Comment: It responds with the full HTML of the page I had requested it to grab, in this case the jira page, if I were to use the link of this stackoverflow page it would return the html of this stack overflow. @RadonirinaMaminiaina

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but any reason you're not using the jira API to give you the data you need directly?

Comment: I could not find any information from the REST Api documentation, and on the community page of Atlassian it takes over a month for a reply on a question.

Comment: My knowledge on APIs is very limited, and using the GET and using the html page seemed the best bet. Also the documentation available on the specific ways to use the GET and REST APIs to receive the information is very limited for Jira. @Shilly

Comment: When you say pull the description, is it the description into meta tag?

Comment: Same, I've never used the API, I just know they have one. Personally I would prefer trying to find the correct api url to GET that will return the details of ION-25843, over scraping the HTML. My collegues would enter a ticket "1337: Description of component scraping is broken." or create a project with the name "Description-writer-component" just to get me to find a better solution.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina The description would be turned into a string to be used elsewhere, in the future it would be used to be a template for future pages. The description is simply just a text box you can add to that is somewhere in the middle of the page. I will attach a photo of the description left by the GET using postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the issue before was based on grabbing the whole HTML, using the rest api was a better solution. Changing the code to:

```
var data = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(response.fields.description);
  }
});
xhr.open("GET", "https://jira2.cerner.com/rest/api/2/issue/ION-25843");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(data);
```

Allows for the code to go out and grab the json of the page, and then grab the specific definition of the page.